# Solidres Joomla 3 Logged in, select any Joomla menu item, erroneously returned to login page

Tags: administrator, menu-item, login, redirect, joomla-3.10

Hi I'm a rank amateur with regard to site development experience,
Last time I put one together was at least a decade ago, much has changed! Decided on Solidres  for numerous reasons, not least they were happy to work with me on our complicated pricing system. We've over 20yrs experience providing tours so around a year ago figured I'd thrown every possible curve ball at the site, all handled admirably, let's publish. A few months ago however, unable to login? Server has an auto-login feature, able to access the backend via that;
[image: Solidres control panel after auto-login] except as soon as I attempt to access *any* menu item (menus themselves will expand no problem) am returned to the login page, which is displaying erroneously, URL in browser address bar (tried alternative browsers, devices, no change) displays correct URL according to whichever menu item I attempted to access, but screen displays login. [image: EG selected Global Configuration, as URL displays]
Also, I'm able to return to the Solidres control panel simply by hitting the back  button. It's been suggested maybe a redirect issue? As I'm unable to select any other pages without being 'logged out'
Last fully functional backup dated last October, everything since then has the same issue, so to save losing 4 months' worth of bookings etc, any advice will be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Miles

Comment: Have you tried to clear cookies and cache on your site? If you can access your Database tables with a product like phpMyAdmin look at the #__extensions table for records with a type of Authentication that are not a part of Joomlas core that is getting involved. You could also try updating configuration.php in you Joomla root directory and change debug=1 and error_reporting=maximum and see if any errors messages are showing when you get thrown back to the login page.

Comment: Aye I clear cache, expired cache & Fn F5 religiously every single time I update anything backend, thanks for the Db tips, will have a look in the morning with fresh head

Comment: Thanks for the advice Irata, I've been up & down the list, unable to find anything to do with authentication. I have however discovered over 5,500 redirects which I've had no hand in setting up, many of them with wp & wordpress in the URL so no idea where they came from! Will try deleting all of those & see if able to remain logged in afterwards

Comment: Do you have  a firewall extension or Akkeba's Admintools running on the site. These products can create redriect rules and .htaccess rules to combat hack attempts.